# Matrix multiply slices of 3D array with slices of 2D array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

A is a 2 dimensional array with dimensions (s, a) and B is a 3 dimensional array with (s, a, a).

I want B[i, :, :] @ A[i, :] for every i in range(s). The result should be arranged in an array of shape (s, a). In code:

```
s = 4
a = 3

A = np.random.uniform(size = [s,a])
B = np.random.uniform(size= [s ,a, a])

C = np.zeros_like(A)
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
  C[i,:] = (A[i,:] @ B[i,:,:])
```

I am looking for C. The catch is that everything should happen in numpy, without slicing A and B.

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik', A, B)`

Answer (score 2):

Numpy does batched multiplication to last two dimensions if the first n-2 dimensions match. You create a extra dimension with `None` and use matmul

```
(A[:,None,:]@B).reshape(A.shape[0],-1)
```